# Opening a Dynamics CRM URL in the Outlook Dynamics Extension

Tags: outlook, microsoft-dynamics-crm

My organisation are adopting Dynamics CRM, and we/they primarily want to use it via the Outlook extension/client. The problem is that we have workflows setup to send emails and notify users whenever a case is created, with a URL to that case.

Is it possible to construct a URL that will open only with the Outlook Dynamics plugin/extension?

Currently it opens in the default browser, and since we are a technology company, a lot of us don't have IE as the default browser. This problem could be mitigated slightly if Dynamics CRM actually worked in any browser (other than IE).

Answer (score 0):

In regards to having a URL that only opens in Outlook; I dont know.

As an alternative, dont use emails, use tasks. A task has a 'regarding' field which is a lookup, when clicked that lookup will open the record (and will do it in Outlook correctly).

So change your workflows to create tasks which populate the regarding field, any content in the email can then be included in the task description.

Answer (score 0):

There is no API which you could use to open records via the Outlook Client.

If the mails do not serve only as information but more as a to-do information, I would second the answer of James and use tasks instead.

However, with the release of Rollup 12 Dynamics CRM gained cross browser support. For Details see: [Browser compatibility introduced with Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2011 Update Rollup 12 or the December 2012 Service Update](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2784954/en)